# wordpress prevent error reporting

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

i'm making a custom theme and noticed one thing. when i try to go directly to my theme index.php file through url (or anypage) for example:

```
localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/index.php
```

this error will appear.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in ... on line...
```

i've tried to download and activate other themes but the result is the same.
how can i prevent this from happening?

i've tried adding the following lines to the wp-config.php

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

but with no results.
i've also tested it "live" but with no results.

thank's in advance.

Comment: check this link https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-undefined-function-get_header-in-index-php-on-line-1/

Comment: thanks for this @PiLHA. i've just checked now in another server without changing the wp-config.php and no errors appeared so, can this be a server configuration? thanks.

Comment: Paste more of error log. PERHAPS `short_open_tag` is not enabled. What version of apache are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but that error occurs when someone tries to directly access the theme's index.php.
For example when a bot tries to access it.

You should never access it directly like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

But rather try it like this:

```
<?php
  if (function_exists('get_header')) {
    get_header();
  } else {
    // Here goes whatever you want to do when the file is accessed directly.
  }
?>
```

Comment: you're correct. this just happens when i access the theme files directly. not only index.php but single.php or anyother file. from what i tested, all of core functions of wordpress like get_header, get_footer, or anyother are undefined if i try to access files directly. The thing is, and im not saying you're wrong, every single theme i've seen only has the <?php get_header(); ?>. The other thing is that on a server that i have, that error is shown and on another server, the error isnt showing. could this be server configurations?

Comment: That could be, I would suggest performing this on another server. It's actually very likely that it could be due to server configurations.

Comment: Kevin Bosman, i already did. checked for php configurations and in one of them i had the display_errors set to show. i change that seting and no errors appeared =) so, case solved... (i guess...)